# Using http range request to stream video files

Tags: python, sockets, http, video, video-streaming

I am trying to make a server which serves video files to clients using http byte serving(range requests),
consider following code

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPStatus
import socketserver
from os import path

PORT = 8000

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    file = R"C:\Users\Prince\Downloads\video.mkv"
    file_size = path.getsize(file)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_GET(self):
        headers = self.headers
        print(headers)

        [start, end] = self.get_range(headers)
        print(start, end)
        body = bytes()
        with open(self.file, 'rb') as f:
            f.seek(start)
            body = f.read(end - start)
        end = start + len(body) - 1

        self.send_response(HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
        self.send_header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "video/x-matroska")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(body))
        self.send_header("Content-Range", "bytes %d-%d/%d" % (start, end, self.file_size))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(body)


    def get_range(self, headers):
        start,size = 0, 1024*1024
        try:
            rkey = headers['Range']
            if not rkey:
                raise "no range header"
            [unit,range] = rkey.split('=')
            if unit != 'bytes':
                raise "unknown unit"
            [s,e] = range.split('-')
            start = int(s)
            e = int(e)
            end = e if not e == 0 else start+size
            return [start, end]
        except:
            return [start, start+size]

handler = MyServer

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler) as httpd:
    print("Server started at localhost:" + str(PORT))
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

but this is not working, the client(vlc) only makes one request and then ends the playback and doesn't play the whole file. f.e
following is the interactions between vlc and script

```
http debug: outgoing request: GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8000 Accept: */* Accept-Language: en_US User-Agent: VLC/3.0.8 LibVLC/3.0.8 Range: bytes=0- 
http debug: incoming response: HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.5 Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 16:07:43 GMT Accept-Range: bytes Content-Type: video/x-matroska Content-Length: 1048576 Content-Range: bytes 0-1048575/285618825
```

no other requests are made by vlc and video is played for this chunk only.

weirdly if I replace `Content-Length` with file size i.e

```py
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(self.file_size))
```

then VLC makes further requests and plays the whole file, also supporting random seeking but I think it's not correct eay since [in Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), it clearly says that content-length should be "real content-length" in range requests, not the full size of the requested resource.

So my question is Is there any other way to actually fix the above code while sending correct `Content-Length`, I am using VLC to play the stream.

Comment: *"...the client(vlc) only makes one request..."* - and what request makes vlc? Ideally provide the full request header, but at least provide request method and the requested range (if any).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've added the headers, please have a look

Comment: vlc requests the full document (`bytes: 0-` means until the end) but you provide only a part, i.e. your response does not match what was requested. vlc kind of expects that the `Content-length`  and the body matches what was requested, i.e. the full file.